# Custom Validator Issue in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-form, zend-validate

I have form called LoginForm, which  extends the RecipeForm which in turn extends Zend_Form.  The RecipeFrom only returns my decorators.

When the form is submitted, I get the following error, 'Message: Method addValidator does not exist'.

```
class Recipe_Form_LoginForm extends Recipe_Form_RecipeForm {
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        $this->setName('loginform')
             ->setAction('/login');


        //  Add Email Element
        $email = $this->addElement('text', 'email', array(
            'label' => 'Email Addresses',
            'required'=> true,
            'size'=>12,
            'filters'=>array('StringTrim'),
            'decorators' => $this->getElementDecorator('email'),

        ));
       $email->addValidator(new Recipe_Validate_EmailAddress(), true, array(
           'messages' => array(
               Recipe_Validate_EmailAddress::INVALID => 
               'Please enter email in correct format',
               Recipe_Validate_EmailAddress::EMAILISEMPTY =>
               'Please enter email address'
       )));
}

class Recipe_Validate_EmailAddress extends Zend_Validate_Abstract
{
    const INVALID           =   'notvalid';
    const EMAILISEMPTY      =   'isempty';

     protected $_messageTemplates = array(
             self::INVALID => "Email is in invalid format",
             self::EMAILISEMPTY => "You have to fill email field"
        );

    public function isValid($value){
        $response = parent::isValid($value);
        if(!$response){
            $this->_message = array(self::INVALID => "Please enter a valid email address");
        }
        return $response;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `$this->addElement()` from within a Zend_Form object, it returns the form object itself, rather than the element you just created.

You can make one of the following changes:

```
$this->addElement('text', 'email', ...);
$email = $this->getElement('email');
$email->addValidator(...);

// or

$email = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('email');
$email->addValidator(...)
      ->setLabel(...)
      ->setRequired(...);
$this->addElement($email);
```

To set your error message, I think you should do this instead of setting $this->_message.

```
$this->_error(self::INVALID);
```

Since it looks like your class is only extending Zend's email validator to override the message, you can override Zend's messages like this and not need to extend the class.  This is taken from a validator in one of my projects, so ignore the extra stuff and just pay attention to the messages for the EmailAddress validator.

```
$this->addElement('text', 'email', array(
        'label' => 'Email Address:',
        'required' => false,
        'filters' => array('StringTrim', 'StringToLower'),
        'validators' => array(
            array('EmailAddress', true, array(
                'messages' => array(
                    Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::INVALID_FORMAT =>
                    "'%value%' is not a valid email address. Example: you@yourdomain.com",
                    Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::INVALID_HOSTNAME =>
                    "'%hostname%' is not a valid hostname for email address '%value%'"
                )
            )),
            array('Db_RecordExists', true, array(
                'table' => 'accounts', 'field' => 'email',
                'messages' => array(
                    Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists::ERROR_NO_RECORD_FOUND =>
                    "No account with that email address was found"
                )
            ))
        ),
        'decorators' => $this->elementDecorators
    ));
```

Comment: drew010, you are absolutely right! I am going to accept your answer because now my validator is called. Can you however tell me why I cannot seem to return my custom error messages? Instead of displaying 'Please enter a valid email address' which i set in, $this->_message = array(self::INVALID => "Please enter a valid email address"); What is displayed is the default Zend Framework message, Array ( [email] => Array ( [0] => emailAddressInvalidFormat [1] => emailAddressInvalidFormat ) [pswd] => Array ( ) [submit] => Array ( ) )

Comment: @stevepop Just updated my answer to address your second question.  Hope that helps.  Feel free to comment back if not or if you have any questions about it.

Comment: HI drew010, Thanks for the new addition. I tried that but I keep getting this error on the form, 'Message: Invalid validator provided to addValidator; must be string or Zend_Validate_Interface'. I am not sure why it is not seeing 'EmailAddress' as a string or object? I find out that the only way I can make it work is if I instantiate Zend_Validate_EmailAddress first, then call the setMessages() and pass an array of messages. But if the above works for you, why do I get that error?

Comment: Yeah that's a little strange, it should see it as a string, in which case it should try to autoload it and I would think if anything you would get an error like "No such validator EmailAddress found in the registry" or something like that.  But its certainly a string, rather than an object.  Is it possible its referring to a different block of code?